# How do you change the CSS of a text input when selected?

Tags: css, input

I want to change the CSS of an `<input type="text">` when the text box is selected; i.e. when the user clicks on the text box, I want different CSS rules to apply. Is there any way to do this using pure CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the focus pseudo-class

```
:focus
```

more info: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus

Answer (score 1):

select the input fields which have attribute of text only

```
input[type="text"]:focus{background-color:yellow;}
```

Select any input field (checkbox,file,hidden,image,password,radio,reset,submit,text)

```
input:focus{background-color:yellow;}
```

Select any textarea

```
textarea:focus{background-color:yellow;}
```

OK that's by CSS however if you are looking to achieve smooth animated effects and have more control over focus/blur it is better to use JQuery or other JavaScript frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Select it using the `:focus` pseudoclass.

Demo at http://dabblet.com/gist/1490497

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following in CSS

E::selection

where E is the element.

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/

You can also use jquery using the

```
$('#element').attr('class', 'new value');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
function change(objNum){
    var objName = "txtbox";
    window.alert(objNum);

    document.getElementByID(objName).className = "franchlinks";

}
</script>

<input type="text" class="yourdefaultclass" id="txtbox1" onclick="change('txtbox1');">
```

Try like this. for lost focus you may try onblur instead of onclick.

Comment: Not only is this overkill, it is not even a clean code.